# How do I save records to production instead of developement?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Ok, so here is my situation. Yesterday I submitted my app to the App Store. Today, I tested it through TestFlight, and discovered my CKRecords are not being uploaded because they are in the development section and not in the production section. I am now making a dummy app where I plan to retrieve all of my CKRecords in the development section, and save them to the production section.

But how do I save records to the production section?

This is my code:

```
func uploadRecordsToProduction() {
        let cloudContainer = CKContainer(identifier: "MyContainserString")
        let publicDatabase = cloudContainer.publicCloudDatabase

        publicDatabase.saveRecord(records, completionHandler: {_,_ in

        })
    }
```

But the records just gets saved to the development section.

Comment: Only apps downloaded from the app store will save to the production database.

Comment: So I will need to submit the dummy app, and then it will work?